# How can i kill or terminate currently executing procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have one stored procedure in mysql which creates several queries and executes. my stored procedure works fine.

But on my screen there is one abort button if user clicks on it,currently executing procedure should stop executing.

How can i achieve this functionality? How can i identify from processlist that particular process is for stored procedure?

Comment: how? I mean my procedure is executing.there are rollback calls if any error occurred. but this is not error i need to kill it from outside of stored procedure code. i.e like from some command?

Comment: Thanks Rahul but how it will identify particular process belong to my(stored procedure name) stored procedure?This will give me currently executing query of procedure. i can't use this as all queries which are generated by procedures are dynamic.

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `KILL process_id`

Comment: Hi ash thank you. please see above comment

Comment: A stored procedure is just a series of queries, so when you show processlist it will show you the queries running and their state, it's not a stack trace that says how it was generated, that is down to you.  You could add comments in your queries and use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see which one is running.

Comment: Infact, you could run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as I previously suggested and edit your question with the result along with the code that calls said query so we can help you.

Comment: Hi ash yeah that's good idea. but then even if I will stop process of that particular query then will it stop execution of stored procedure?